# error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scraperwiki': Permission denied

Tags: python

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scraperwiki
copying scraperwiki/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scraperwiki
copying scraperwiki/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scraperwiki
copying scraperwiki/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scraperwiki
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scraperwiki
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scraperwiki': Permission denied
```

Comment: What commands did you run?

Comment: pip install scraperwiki

Comment: I am USing this Command: $ pip install scraperwiki

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you also do `pip --version`?

Comment: pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `pip` to install `scraperwiki` with the `--user` option so that the package is installed in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`:

```
pip install --user scraperwiki
```

This way, you don't have to run the command with `sudo` because otherwise you would need `sudo` to install into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`; this is why you got an error about permissions.

Note that if you have a newer version of `pip` (1.5.6 and above), `pip install scraperwiki` would have defaulted to `pip install --user scraperwiki` because of this [patch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/1.5.6-4ubuntu1).